# counting the number of recursive calls in java

Tags: java, recursion

I have written a piece of Java code to find an integer in an integer list

```
    static int search(int x, List a) {
       if (a.isEmpty()) {

           throw new IllegalStateException("integer not in list");
       }
           if (x == a.getHead()) { 

           return x;
       }
       return search(x, a.getTail());
   }}
```

But what I want to do is rather than return the value of X, I want to return its position in the list. So for example if in x = 5 and a = 1,2,3,4,7,5
then I want to return 6. But I have no idea how to count the number of recursive calls.
Any clues?

Comment: Pass it as a third parameter to the function, increment at every call, return it when element is found. (Since you seem to want that to be 1-based and not 0-based, send `1` on the first call).

Comment: Or just return `1 + search(x, a.getTail())` in the recursive call and return 0 when you find the element.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add a third parameter - `count`.

```
static int search(int x, List a, int count) {
    if (a.isEmpty()) {

       throw new IllegalStateException("integer not in list");
    }
       if (x == a.getHead()) { 

            return count;
       }
       return search(x, a.getTail(), count + 1); // incrementing the count here
    }
}
```

To call it, either pass in `1` for the count to count the number of calls you make to `search`, or pass `0` to only count the *recursive* calls.

Answer (score 0):

What about using `yourList.indexOf(yourElement)`

Here is a link to the documentation : 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)

I Hop this helps !

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is an exercise to learn about recursing a list, so that won't really be useful.

Comment: The OP's List class is not that of java SE.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want this to be 1-based and not 0 based, you can return `1 + search(x, a.getTail())` in the recursive call (this way you'll count the number of times you call the method, that is the current one (`1`) plus, recursively, all the others).

Then when you find the element you can return 0.